# How can I output contents of an array to a HTML div container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to output the contents of an array to a div container on my html file but I am stumped. Here is what I have:

```
function change_string() {
    var $container = $('.container');
    $container.html('');

    var myString= streams.home[myStringNo];
    var $myString= $('<div></div>');

    $myString.text('@' + myString.user + ': ' + myString.message + 'Generated:     ' + timeStamp);
    $myString.appendTo($container);

    myStringNo ++;
};
```

The line: $myString.appendTo($container); shows a single string per button click, which is this:

```
 <INPUT type="button" value="See next Random String" name="button1"   onClick="change_string()"> <br>
```

How do I

A) Output contents of my array instead of a single string in the container

and

B) How do I reference each different button on my page? All other buttons are like this, and I am at my blocking point:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="See strings for jmcgui05" name="button2" onClick="change_string()"> <br>
```

Basically, for when button2 is clicked, the container should be populated with the strings for user2.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code please using jsfiddle or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you can output the contents of an array using jQuery's `.each()` function.  You basically loop through the array and concatenate the strings together:

```
function output_strings(source_array)
{    
    var container = $('.container');
    var output = "";

    $.each(source_array, function(i, string) {
        output += string + ' ';
    });

    container.text(output);
}
```

For your second question, "How do I reference each different button on my page?"  The best way to do this is to give each button a unique ID attribute:

```
<button id="button_1">Button One</button>
```

And then use jQuery to setup a listener for that specific button:

```
$('#button_1').on('click', function(){
    // Do something
});
```

I put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/ah0zt2y4/2/) to demo these concepts.  And [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) are the docs for the `.each()` function.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each object in your `streams.home[messageNumber]` array with jQuery's `$.each()` method. The reason for using this over javascript's built-in `array.forEach` method is mainly to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

HTML

```
<input type='button' class='message-btn' value='...' name='...' />
```

JS

```
var messageNumber = 0;

$(function() {
    $('.message-btn').click(function() {

        var messageLines = [];
        $.each(streams.home[messageNumber], function(i, message) {
            messageLines.push([
                '<div>',
                '@', stream.user, ': ',
                stream.message, 
                'Generated:     ',
                timeStamp,
                '</div>'
            ].join(''));
        });

        $container.append(messageLines.join(''));

        messageNumber++;
    });
});
```

**Some notes on style**

1. Scrap inline javascript and use jQuery's event handler. That way you don't have to manually attach the onclick attribute to each of your buttons.
2. Use [*string1*, *string2*, *string3*, ..., *stringN*].join(''); for concatenating strings; its much more efficient in javascript and easier to read and manage. :]
3. Try to be more concise in your variable naming. You should try to ditch the 'my' prefix and just call `myString` something like `messageText`. Not only will it make it easier for you, it'll make it easier for people on SO who are trying to help you.
4. Also, In the future, try to keep your code format clean so people can help you easier.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

An important part of the javascript you provided is that you will need global variables to hold onto the index, home hash, etc. Try this:

```js
var myStringNo = 0;
var homeArray = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    homeArray.push({user: "User " + i, message: "Message " + i});
}
var streams = {
    home: homeArray    
};

window.change_string = function () {
    var $container = $('.container');
    $container.html('');

    var myString = streams.home[myStringNo % streams.home.length];
    var $myString = $('<div></div>');

    $myString.text('@' + myString.user + ': ' + myString.message + ', Generated:     ' + new Date().getTime());
    $myString.appendTo($container);
    myStringNo++;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<INPUT type="button" value="See next Random String" name="button1" onClick="change_string()">
<br>
<div class="container"></div>
```

And if you want it to be truly random, replace

```
var myString = streams.home[myStringNo % streams.home.length];
```

with

```
var myString = streams.home[Math.floor(streams.home.length * Math.random())];
```